# Regex pattern in HTML5 example solution for regular expression

Tags: regex, html, character-encoding, expression

I am testing the patterns-attribute for input elements and I built a regex that should do the following: for testing if the input is a valid email address. Is it possible to group various regex expressions like I did in HTML5?

I tried to group like this:

```
pattern="[ ([a-zA-Z0-9+-.]{1,}) ([@]{1}) ([a-zA-Z0-9+-.]{1,}) ([.]{1}) ([a-zA-Z0-9+-.]{1,}) ]{5,254}"
```

1. Any chars from `a-z` and `A-Z` and `0-9` and `+-.` are allowed with a minimum of 1 char.
2. It should be followed by a `@`.
3. Any chars from `a-z` and `A-Z` and `0-9` and `+-.` are allowed with a minimum of 1 char.
4. It should be followed by a dot `.`.
5. Any chars from `a-z` and `A-Z` and `0-9` and `+-.` are allowed with a minimum of 1 char.
6. In total are 5-254 chars allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would satisfy all your conditions. You don't need to add space within the pattern,

```
^(?=.{5,254}$)[a-zA-Z0-9+-.]{1,}@[a-zA-Z0-9+-.]{1,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9+-.]{1,}
```

Add a single character in the demo input and you could see the difference.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cK0bW3)

Comment: thank you. do you know any nice tutorials for regex in html5?

Comment: @DominikZinser i know regexes. But i donno specific regex for html5. 90% of regexes would be same for all the languages. Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html to learn about regexes.